# Sum up Double ReadLine values?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# programming and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because I can't sum up numbers that are Double. If I input 2,5 and 2,5 I get 5, but if I enter 2.5 and 2.5 I get zero when I use a dot instead of a comma between the numbers. Why this?

I add some of my code:

```
 private void ReadInputAndSumNumbers()
    {
        while (!done)
        {
            Console.Write("Number: ");
            if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
            {
                if (num == 0)
                {
                    done = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    sum += num;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My settings are to use a comma, but I would like the user to be able to enter a value with dot also

Comment: Can you show your input code?

Comment: The format of number accepted is dependent on your culture settings

Answer (score 4):

How are you converting your ReadLine input into Doubles? Most of the conversion operations are locale-specific, so if your Windows settings have `,` as the decimal separator, this setting is respected.

**Example:**

```
string enteredByUser = Console.ReadLine();

// uses user-specific Windows settings (decimal separator might be ",")
double myDouble1 = double.Parse(enteredByUser);

// uses default settings (decimal separator is always ".")
double myDouble2 = double.Parse(enteredByUser, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

*A short side note*: If you parse user input, you should look into [`double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx), since this is more robust than `double.Parse` or `Convert.ToDouble`, since it allows you to detect faulty input without resorting to exception handling.

---

**EDIT:** If you want to support *both* comma and dot, you need to convert dots into commas (or vice versa) first. [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) can help you here. Note, though, that this approach will break if the user tries to enter a thousands separator (`1.000,00` -> `1.000.00` or `1,000,00` -> error). The recommended way to do it is to

- only accept the decimal separator specified in Windows, if the input comes from an end-user (i.e., keep your code as it is) and
- only accept the neutral culture (`.`), if the input comes from some machine-generated output or file.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use your code like this: if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out num)) but it's not working?! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: What did you do wrong? You didn't read the documentation of double.TryParse before using it. ;-) Click on the link behind "double.TryParse" in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A sample for caculate the double sum

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var retVal = 0.0;
    var sum = 0.0;
    while (true) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter input:");  
        string line = Console.ReadLine();  
        if (line == "exit")  
        {
            break;
        }


        double.TryParse(line, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out retVal);
        sum += retVal;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Double Value : {0}", sum ));  
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```